# How to apply text to irregular non-flat surface?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, adobe-illustrator, effects

I was wondering how I can make something like the text in the yellow? It doesn't seem to be a warp tool.

[image]

Comment: This asks about a field of dots, but the concept is the same: [How do I create a depth illusion effect with a spots pattern in Illustrator?](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/53266/how-do-i-create-a-depth-illusion-effect-with-a-spots-pattern-in-illustrator/53279#53279)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]

In Adobe Illustrator use envelope distortion "With Mesh" for this. There are two versions:

- Left: only some random deformations Object > Envelope Distortion > Make with Mesh (the mesh is left visible)
- Right: added another envelope "Make with top object" for perspective. The added envelope is a trapezium.

You might also want to add some shading. For this you can add a grey or colored gradient mesh on the top, then play with the blending mode and opacity in the `Appearance` panel.